# ionic app three different layouts

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to make an app with ionic which has three different main layouts.

1. with no header just an bg-image and a input field
2. header with one button and a list
3. heade with two buttons and than four tabs

how do I habe to structer the layouts? My first idea was:

index.html

```
<body ng-app="starter">
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
</body>
```

And than for layout 2 (overview.html):

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-balanced">
  <ion-nav-buttons side="primary">
    ...
  </ion-nav-buttons>
</ion-nav-bar>
<ion-view view-title="Title Page 2" class="has-header">
  <ion-content>
    ...
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

And for layout 3:
The abstract layout (tabs.html):

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-balanced has-tabs-top">
  <ion-nav-back-button>
  </ion-nav-back-button>
  <ion-nav-buttons side="primary">
      ...
    </ion-nav-buttons>
</ion-nav-bar>

<ion-tabs class="tabs-striped tabs-top tabs-background-balanced">

<ion-tab title="Dash" icon-off="ion-android-chat" icon-on="ion-android-chat" href="#/tab/dash">
  <ion-nav-view name="tab-dash"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>
...
</ion-tabs>
```

And the specific tab-layout (tab-dash.html):

```
<ion-view view-title="Dashboard">
  <ion-content>
    ...
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

My app.js:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('tab', {
    url: '/tab',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
  })

  .state('tab.dash', {
    url: '/dash',
    views: {
      'tab-dash': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-dash.html',
        controller: 'DashCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('overview', {
      url: '/',
      templateUrl: 'templates/overview.html',
      controller: 'OverviewCtrl'
    })
```

This doesn't work correct... the title from layout 2 doesn't show up and the tabs doesn't "fusion" with the header correct. Is the hole structer wrong or just the layout files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the nav bar inside your "root" index.html and control its visibility using the following attributes which might prevent you from having to declare multiple nav-bars in different files.

```
<ion-view view-title="My View Title" hide-nav-bar="true">
```

in ionics started template for tabbed applications the suggested approach appears to be to place the navbar outside

Source: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-tabs/blob/master/index.html

Plnkr for Starter Template with Tabs: http://plnkr.co/edit/qYMCrt?p=preview

Comment: But how can I handle the different buttons? Layout 2 has just one button and Layout 3 has two.